# Setting ContentOffset using buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, scrollview

I have made a .xib file with couple of buttons and attached it to the inputAccessoryView. I made this section scrollable with scrollView, however I have to add additional functionality using buttons (arrows). Clicking forward arrow it should go to the end and back arrow would take as to the original position.

[image: first position - start]
[image: second position - end]

I made whole ScrollView in UI without any code. It works well, those buttons are on top of this view.I was thinking of using IBAction of these buttons and changing ContentOffSet. I am struggling with implementation. I will be grateful for some tips.

*Class for implementation:*

```
#import "KCSearchInputAccessoryView.h"

 @implementation KCSearchInputAccessoryView

 + (KCSearchInputAccessoryView *)viewFromNib {
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
return [[bundle loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
}

- (IBAction)backBtnTapped:(id)sender {

 }

 - (IBAction)forwardBtnTapped:(id)sender {

 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with changing ContentOffset, but...

Assuming you have references to the buttons, a better approach may be using `func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)`

```
IBAction func rightButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.theScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(postsButton.frame, animated: true)
}

IBAction func leftButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.theScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(chatsButton.frame, animated: true)
}
```

This would also "slide" the buttons across.

Edit: gotten so used to people using Swift...

Objective-C version... and, instead of using the individual Button frames, just create a rect at the beginning or end of the scroll view content:

```
- (IBAction)backBtnTapped:(id)sender {
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    [_theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:r animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)forwardBtnTapped:(id)sender {
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(_theScrollView.contentSize.width - 1, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    [_theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:r animated:YES];
}
```

Example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/ScratchPad

Comment: That's interesting approach. I have edited my question, adding class with implementation. In .h file add those buttons as IBOutlet and so myScrollView so make it visible for .m ? Not sure how to get that functionality of scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: I'm assuming you have the Chats, People, SuperUsers, etc buttons connected in some way?

Comment: Well not at this moment. Just added them in Interface while creating this view. I will be adding functionality later on when this scrolling is done.

Comment: OK, then go ahead and connect them to IBOutlets... that will give you access to their frames.

Comment: Okey. What about the scrollRectToVisible func? What do I need to import?

Comment: Edited my answer, along with a sample to help see how it would work.